# How to avoid the idle connections in postgres 9.3

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

We are using postgres 9.3 version. And we are getting connections like "set extra_float_digits =3" as idle minimum 40 connections . I'm surprised even though I disabled that parameter in conf file still getting too many connections.

Can anyone suggest me to avoid those connections in postgres 9.3 without using pgbouncer.

Comment: please provide info on your client. this problem has nothing to do with postgres. maybe it's java pool if you have exactly 40 connection?.. or other session pooler

Answer (score 0):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html:

> extra_float_digits (integer)
>
> This parameter adjusts the number of
>   digits displayed for floating-point values, including float4, float8,
>   and geometric data types. The parameter value is added to the standard
>   number of digits (FLT_DIG or DBL_DIG as appropriate). The value can be
>   set as high as 3, to include partially-significant digits; this is
>   especially useful for dumping float data that needs to be restored
>   exactly. Or it can be set negative to suppress unwanted digits. See
>   also Section 8.1.3.

**extra_float_digits has nothing to do with idle connections**. To get rid of `idle` connections, close session.

Comment: Thanks, but I had disabled that parameter to 0. Still am getting connections . Can you suggest me to avoid those

Answer (score 0):

You can control number of active and idle connection creation using property file configuration. For example, below is the configuration for Spring Boot Project and Postgres DB.

*Note: This configuration is Yaml file*

```
datasource:
  driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
  url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db
  username: test
  password: test
  tomcat:
  # default value is 100 but postgres' default is 100 as well. To prevent "PSQLException: FATAL: sorry, too many
  # clients already", we decrease the max-active value here. Which should be sufficient, by the way
    max-active: 10
    max-idle: 10
    min-idle: 5
    max-wait: 30000
    time-between-eviction-runs-millis: 5000
    min-evictable-idle-time-millis: 60000
  jmx-enabled: true
jmx-enabled: true
```

In this configuration, while creating connection for the first time there will be 10 Idle connection. After 1min of time (as per the coonfig) there will be 5 Idle connection.

In this case you can control number of Idle connection creation.

And If you execute below query in your DB, you can see list of connections

```
select * from pg_stat_activity;

select datname, count(*) from pg_stat_activity where state = 'idle' group by datname;

SELECT count(*), state FROM pg_stat_activity GROUP BY 2;
```